# All possible (monogamous) pairings of two lists (of boys and girls)

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I have these two lists:

```
boys  = [1,2,3]
girls = [1,2,3]
```

How would you build all possible (monogamous) pairings `[boy, girl]`? With only 3 of both `boys` and `girls`, I think this is the list of *all* the possible pairings:

```
[
 [[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]],
 [[1,1], [2,3], [3,2]],
 [[1,2], [2,1], [3,3]],
 [[1,2], [2,3], [3,2]],
 [[1,3], [2,1], [3,2]],
 [[1,3], [2,2], [3,1]]
]
```

How would you do it in general (in above format)? This is what I've been able to come up ...

```
pairs = list(itertools.product(boys, girls))
possible_pairings = []
for i, p in enumerate(pairs):
    if i % len(boys) == 0:
        print
    print list(p),
#   possible_pairings.append(pairing)
```

... which gives this output.

```
[1, 1] [1, 2] [1, 3]
[2, 1] [2, 2] [2, 3]
[3, 1] [3, 2] [3, 3]
```

**How would you find all possible pairings (written out above for specific example)?** These are like the 6 ways you'd have to multiply elements of a 3x3 matrix (to find its determinant). :)

### Sven's almost answer (with my `enumerate` addition)

```
possible_pairings = []
possible_pairings_temp = []
boys  = ["b1", "b2", "b3"]
girls = ["g1", "g2", "g3"]

for girls_perm in itertools.permutations(girls):
    for i, (b, g) in enumerate(zip(boys, girls_perm)):
        possible_pairings_temp.append([b, g])
        if (i + 1) % len(boys) == 0: # we have a new pairings list
            possible_pairings.append(possible_pairings_temp)
            possible_pairings_temp = []
    print

print possible_pairings
```

And this completely satisfies the format in the question.

Comment: What about homosexual pairings? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are describing are the permutations of a set.  Simply leave the boys in the given order, and iterate through alll permutations of the girls -- this will give you all possible pairings:

```
boys = ["b1", "b2", "b3"]
girls = ["g1", "g2", "g3"]
for girls_perm in itertools.permutations(girls):
    for b, g in zip(boys, girls_perm):
        print b + g,
    print
```

prints

```
b1g1 b2g2 b3g3
b1g1 b2g3 b3g2
b1g2 b2g1 b3g3
b1g2 b2g3 b3g1
b1g3 b2g1 b3g2
b1g3 b2g2 b3g1
```

Comment: Could you please show a specific example using [itertools' permutations()](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)? I know that "the batteries are included", but alas I haven't found them in _itertools_.

Comment: @courteous: I sincerely do not understand what you are asking.  You haven't found `permutations` in `itertools`?  How did you look for it?

Comment: How would you make each line in your answer (say, `b1g1 b2g2 b3g3`) be in its own list (as in my example of all possible pairings)?
I've added the `enumerate` to your `zip`, but I get one superfluous (and wrong) `[[1, 1]]` pairings list (I've updated the question).

Comment: OK, I figured it out ... modulus operator `%` takes precedence over addition, therefore the braces around `(i + 1)`. Thank you Sven.