# Find all combinations of pairings between two lists x and y, such that all elements from y are paired with exactly one from x

Tags: python, list, combinations

I am trying to find in python3 each unique combination of elements from two lists x and y, such that for each combination, all elements from list y are paired up with exactly one element from list x (`min(x,y)` ^ `max(x,y)` combos). For example, with the following:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
y = [1, 2, 3]

combos = get_combos(x,y)
for combo in combos:
    print(combo)
```

...I want to write `get_combos(x, y)` such that it returns a list of 27 combos of pairs which, when printed, looks like:

```
[('a', 1) ('a', 2) ('a', 3)]
[('a', 1) ('a', 2) ('b', 3)]
[('a', 1) ('a', 2) ('c', 3)]
[('a', 1) ('b', 2) ('a', 3)]
[('a', 1) ('b', 2) ('b', 3)]
[('a', 1) ('b', 2) ('c', 3)]
[('a', 1) ('c', 2) ('a', 3)]
[('a', 1) ('c', 2) ('b', 3)]
[('a', 1) ('c', 2) ('c', 3)]
[('b', 1) ('a', 2) ('a', 3)]
[('b', 1) ('a', 2) ('b', 3)]
[('b', 1) ('a', 2) ('c', 3)]
[('b', 1) ('b', 2) ('a', 3)]
[('b', 1) ('b', 2) ('b', 3)]
[('b', 1) ('b', 2) ('c', 3)]
[('b', 1) ('c', 2) ('a', 3)]
[('b', 1) ('c', 2) ('b', 3)]
[('b', 1) ('c', 2) ('c', 3)]
[('c', 1) ('a', 2) ('a', 3)]
[('c', 1) ('a', 2) ('b', 3)]
[('c', 1) ('a', 2) ('c', 3)]
[('c', 1) ('b', 2) ('a', 3)]
[('c', 1) ('b', 2) ('b', 3)]
[('c', 1) ('b', 2) ('c', 3)]
[('c', 1) ('c', 2) ('a', 3)]
[('c', 1) ('c', 2) ('b', 3)]
[('c', 1) ('c', 2) ('c', 3)]
```

I have looked at itertools.combinations, itertools.product, and itertools.permutations, but none of them seem to give me exactly what I'm looking for. itertools.permutations gets me close when used with `zip` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8886716/12870873)), but there the resulting lists are exclusive in the sense that no element from either list may be repeated in a single combination (e.g. `[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 3)]` would be left out), which is not what I want. Will itertools work for this or is this something that needs to be written from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it looks like task for `itertools.product` and `zip`, I would do:

```
import itertools
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
y = [1, 2, 3]
for t in itertools.product(x,repeat=3):
    print(list(zip(t,y)))
```

Output:

```
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3)]
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3)]
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 3)]
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)]
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3)]
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
[('a', 1), ('c', 2), ('a', 3)]
[('a', 1), ('c', 2), ('b', 3)]
[('a', 1), ('c', 2), ('c', 3)]
[('b', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3)]
[('b', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3)]
[('b', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 3)]
[('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)]
[('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3)]
[('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
[('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('a', 3)]
[('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('b', 3)]
[('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('c', 3)]
[('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3)]
[('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3)]
[('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 3)]
[('c', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)]
[('c', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3)]
[('c', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
[('c', 1), ('c', 2), ('a', 3)]
[('c', 1), ('c', 2), ('b', 3)]
[('c', 1), ('c', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

Note odometer-like nature of [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Answer (score 1):

Basic recursive solution without imports:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
y = [1, 2, 3]
def groups(d, c=[]):
  if len(c) == len(x):
    yield list(zip(c, y))
  else:
    for i in d:
       yield from groups(d, c+[i])

print(list(groups(x)))
```

Output:

```
[[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3)], [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3)], [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 3)], [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)], [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3)], [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)], [('a', 1), ('c', 2), ('a', 3)], [('a', 1), ('c', 2), ('b', 3)], [('a', 1), ('c', 2), ('c', 3)], [('b', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3)], [('b', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3)], [('b', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 3)], [('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)], [('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3)], [('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)], [('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('a', 3)], [('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('b', 3)], [('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('c', 3)], [('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3)], [('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3)], [('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 3)], [('c', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)], [('c', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3)], [('c', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)], [('c', 1), ('c', 2), ('a', 3)], [('c', 1), ('c', 2), ('b', 3)], [('c', 1), ('c', 2), ('c', 3)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a combination of combinations_with_replacement and permutations that yield the 27.

```
a = set([])
for i in combinations_with_replacement(['a','b','c'],3):
    for j in permutations(i):
        a.add(j)

assert len(a) == 27

for i in a:
    print(list(zip(i,[1,2,3])))
```

yields:

```
[('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3)]
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 3)]
[('b', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3)]
[('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 3)]
[('c', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)]
[('c', 1), ('c', 2), ('c', 3)]
[('a', 1), ('c', 2), ('a', 3)]
[('c', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
[('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3)]
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3)]
[('a', 1), ('c', 2), ('b', 3)]
[('a', 1), ('c', 2), ('c', 3)]
[('c', 1), ('c', 2), ('a', 3)]
[('c', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3)]
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)]
[('c', 1), ('c', 2), ('b', 3)]
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3)]
[('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('a', 3)]
[('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
[('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3)]
[('b', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 3)]
[('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('c', 3)]
[('b', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3)]
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3)]
[('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)]
[('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('b', 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import itertools
L = ['a','b','c']
P = list( itertools.product(L, repeat=3) )
[ [(x,1),(y,2),(z,3)] for x,y,z in P ]
```